# How to Do Trailing Stop & Conditional Exit?

Tags: pine-script

I'm backtesting a strategy about when close > VWAP = Entry , When close < VWAP = Exit or when I lose -8% , then exit.

The problem is when i use "When" to decide exit point , the Strategy Tester has no trade why is that and how to solve ? Thanks so much !

```
strategy("Long VWAP")

LongCondition01 = vwap > close

OutTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0
TimePeriod = time > timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2010, 01, 01, 0, 0)

if(LongCondition01 and OutTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
if strategy.position_size != 0
    StopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.92
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop=StopLoss, when = close < vwap)
```

And , I would also want to ask how to set a trailing stop for -10% from the top ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but as far as I understand it's not possible to use multiple if statement after a strategy.entry point was opened.
So you could use

```
if(LongCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
else
    if(strategy.position_size != 0
        StopLoss
        strategy.exit
```

perhaps this works. Please have a look on the PineScript Docs for Conditional Statements.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html#id1

This isn't a whole solution, but for me it worked some kind – at least, I get now an exit and a close position on my trade.

I still struggle with the same problem, how to get multiple stops (trailing-stop) in a trade position.